# Finding length of a segment inside a triangle with following conditions :

Tags: geometry

> In $\triangle ABC$, $AB=10$, $AC=16$
>
> $G$ is the centroid of $\triangle ABC$, and $AD$ is median.
>
> Point $K$ is such that $B-K-C$ .
>
> $GK$ parallel $AB$, $KD=2$.
>
> Find $AK.$

I have taken a long time but not find how its answer please help me.I tried it very hard but couldn't find any solution

Comment: Pleas show us some of your thoughts. This is the second of your questions which I see appearing on this site with just a problem statement. People can help you much better if you show us where exactly you are stuck. Moreover, people are more willing to help if you show us some effort. Moreover, what do you mean with the point $K$ is such that $B-K-C$? As a $\textbf{hint }$: try to draw this (a sketch is sufficient), it might give you ideas.

Comment: Actually I am operating this site by mobile so I can not upload pictures I am stuck from first please help me

Comment: I did not mean that you should upload a picture, but it might help you to take the right steps. Anyway, could you clarify what you mean with 'Point $K$ is such that $B - K - C$? Do you mean that the point $K$ is a point on the line through $B$ and $C$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$1)$ $G$ is the centroid then $AG=2GD$ and once $GK||AB$ then, by Thales's Theorem $BK=2KD=4$;

$2)$ Once $D$ is the midpoint then $CD=BD=4+2=6\to BC=12$;

$3)$ Now using cosine law at the triangle $ABC$ and $ABK$ we get:

$$16^2=10^2+12^2-2\cdot10\cdot12\cdot\cos B\\
AK^2=4^2+10^2-2\cdot4\cdot10\cdot\cos B$$

and then you get $AK$ using $\cos B$ from the first equation.

Comment: @AtharvaShetty: you are welcome, but next time try to explain your own thoughts in the question.